# Typescript declared type not respected

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript, so this might be a dumb question.
I've got a function such as:

```
interface MyType {
   myField: string
   myOtherField: string
}

const myFunction = (input: MyType) => { ... }
```

I've noticed that this function is able to receive values which are not `MyType`, e.g. I've seen values such as `MyType[]` or even `string`.

Now, probably this happens because Typescript simply output Javascript code, which does not know about types at all.

Is there a way to enforce type checking and throw an `Error` if such mismatch happens?

Edit: for future reference see https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime

Comment: Where have you seen these values ? If you call this function from typescript you get a compile time error as expected. If you call from JS, there is no enforcement of types in any way at runtime

Comment: Just copied your code into TypeScript playground. It shows compile error.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20myField%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20myOtherField%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFunction%20%3D%20(input%3A%20MyType)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(input.myField)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AmyFunction('hello')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A

Comment: @MjZac Those functions are used from other libraries and called at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are checked by the TypeScript compiler and are erased during compilation.

While you are working within TypeScript, you get all of the checking that you expect:

```
interface MyType {
   myField: string
   myOtherField: string
}

const myFunction = (input: MyType) => {
    return input.myField;
};

// OK
myFunction({ myField: '', myOtherField: '' });

// NOT OK
myFunction([{ myField: '', myOtherField: '' }]);
```

But if you call your transpiled JavaScript from another JavaScript file at runtime there is no type checking. *Type checking at runtime is not a feature of TypeScript*.

## TS* / Safer TypeScript

There was a brief initiative to create a [runtime type safe compiler for TypeScript](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/07/what-is-ts-and-how-is-it-safer-typescript/), but it didn't gain traction and hasn't been updated since 2014.

Comment: The Safer Typescript sounded interesting. I think the approach would have been the same as the one applied in Kotlin for throwing exceptions in case of null values, additional code generation.

Comment: That's right - it was going to be an alternate compiler that inserted type checks that would actually run (at some performance cost). I don't think it made it out of research and only worked with TypeScript 0.9.5.

Comment: A pity. I would have loved it. I think the performance penalty is negligible